# ansible command for double qoutes to a variable

Tags: ansible

```
- find: ^CODEDEPLOY_USER=""
replace: CODEDEPLOY_USER=""{{ app_install_user }}""
```

"/"{{ app_install_user }}/"" something as such, This is on the vars folder of a play

I would require to add the variable in quotes on the vars of roles. roles/xxxx/vars/main.yml

app_install_user is added on group_vars of ansible

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
replace: CODEDEPLOY_USER='"{{ app_install_user }}"'
```

Hope that will help you.